Using central limit theorem as a large deviations theorem
The Central limit theorem states that (under some conditions) the sample mean $y_N = \frac{1}{N} \sum_1^N X_k$ is distributed like a normal variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/N$. So if I want to study the probability of deviations from the mean I get
$$P(y_N) \sim e^{-\frac{N(y_N-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \sim e^{-NI(y)}$$
where I(y) decreases when $|y_N-\mu|$ increases. Isn't this the same as a large deviations principle?
I read (in the answers to this post) that it is wrong because CLT is used to study $O(\sqrt{n})$ deviations from $N\mu$ and not $O(n)$, but studying the CLT proof I don't get why. I'd be glad if someone could point the part of the classic proof (using the characteristic function) where this restriction comes from.

I'm not sure what opinion you read stating this is wrong, but they're clearly very-closely related.  One way to link the two is through the theory of random signals/"cylinder sets"; you can view the asymptotic equipartition property as an alternate "representation" of the same idea as the central limit theorem.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Which large deviations principle do you have in mind? This one, for example?

@J.G. Yes, but even without referring to the precise form of the rate function, the general result that P(y) ~ exp(-N I(y))
